# sed's c command outputs current line no matter what

Tags: sed

Here's what I do:

```
$ echo '1
2
3' | sed -n '
    x
    c\
test
    x
'
test
test
test
```

Is it expected behavior? I'm running `gnu sed 4.2.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

excerpting from the info page: "output
     the lines of text which follow this command ... A new cycle is started after this command is done"

Presumably then, the last `x` command is never used.

Comment: +1 The fact is not mentioned in the man page.

Comment: Indeed, I was judging from man page.

Comment: A link to the manual would be apt: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: This behavior for the c command is also specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): "*Delete the pattern space. With a 0 or 1 address or at the end of a 2-address range, place text on the output and start the next cycle.*"